# Convert PDF buffer to PNG buffer

Tags: node.js, pdf, buffer, png

Is there a way to convert a PDF buffer to an png image Buffer ?

All I can do is convert the pdf buffer to base 64 but then I don't know what to do next.

Thanks !

Comment: Did you get the solution? I have the same problem

Comment: @Muhzin yes, I just posted the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just used https://github.com/yakovmeister/pdf2image, works good for my use case but requires some native deps :

```
import { fromBuffer as convertPdfToPng } from 'pdf2pic'

const pdf2picOptions = {
  format: 'png',
  width: 2550,
  height: 3300,
  density: 330,
  savePath: './output/from-buffer-to-base64',
}

const convert = convertPdfToPng(pdfBuffer, pdf2picOptions)

const pageOutput = await convert(pageNumber, true)
const pngBuffer = Buffer.from(pageOutput.base64, 'base64')
```

Comment: You can just update the `convertOptions` to buffer
here it is:
```const pageOutputBuffer = await convert(pageNumber, {responseType: "buffer"})```