# Convert PDFs to text via tesseract.js in memory

Tags: javascript, pdf, buffer, tesseract

I wanted to grab all of the text from a PDF via [tesseract.js](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/) and did so fairly easily.

```js
"use strict";
 
const fs = require("fs");
const { fromPath } = require("pdf2pic");
const { createWorker } = require("tesseract.js");
 
const tempImagePath = "./temp_images/";
 
const pdfToImageOptions = {
    density: 300,
    quality: 100,
    width: 850,
    height: 1100,
    preserveAspectRatio: true,
    savePath: tempImagePath,
};
 
async function convertPdfAndExtractText(pdfPath) {
    // Create a temporary directory for images if it doesn't exist
    if (!fs.existsSync(tempImagePath)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(tempImagePath, { recursive: true });
    }
 
    if (!fs.existsSync(pdfPath)) {
        console.error("PDF file does not exist:", pdfPath);
        return;
    }
 
    // Initialize the Tesseract worker outside the loop
    const worker = await createWorker();
    let allData = "";
 
    try {
        const convert = fromPath(pdfPath, pdfToImageOptions);
 
        // Convert all pages
        const imagesInfo = await convert.bulk(-1);
        for (const imageInfo of imagesInfo) {
            const { data } = await worker.recognize(tempImagePath + imageInfo.name);
            allData += data.text;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error occurred:", error);
    } finally {
        // Terminate the worker in the finally block
        await worker.terminate();
 
        // Delete the temporary image folder and its contents
        try {
            fs.rmSync(tempImagePath, { recursive: true, force: true });
        } catch (deleteError) {
            console.error(`Error deleting temporary image folder ${tempImagePath}:`, deleteError);
        }
        console.log("OCR'd text:");
        console.log(allData);
    }
}
  
convertPdfAndExtractText("./pdfs/five.pdf");
```

But I do not want to write anything to my filesystem/create a file. Since I know tesseract.js can read [buffers and base64 strings](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/blob/master/docs/image-format.md) I thought it would be simple to convert a PDF to an image buffer and then have tesseract.js grab that text... but I haven't found anything.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64102183/convert-pdf-buffer-to-png-buffer) is the closest to my question, with the answer being of course to write to the filesystem and thus not keep the images in memory.

Is there a way to have tesseract.js get the text off of a PDF file without writing any files?